# Saving and restoring a fragment state like Play Store

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-architecture-navigation

Right now I'm developing an application, which basically uses this components for navigation and visualization:

```
 - Navigation component,
 - ViewPager,
 - FragmentStatePagerAdapter,
 - TabLayout.
```

In the application there is 7 fixed tab (fragment). Most of them have one RecyclerView and I fetch the data from a server.

I have two problem with this solution:

1. When I click an item in one of the `RecyclerView`, I use navigation component's `navigate()` method. Then I press back button, and the list is 'making a network call again' and scroll to the top (not retain the fragment's state).
2. When I swiping in the `ViewPager` it doesn't save the fragment's state and reloading them all the time. Yes, I'm familiar with the  `setOffscreenPageLimit()` method, and it's working, but according to the docummentation: "You should keep this limit low, especially if your pages have complex layouts", so I shouldn't set it to 7.

So basically my question is, how Google do it on Play Store? Play Store has planty of tabs on the bottom navigation, plenty of tabs on the top, but somehow it seems to save all of my previous navigation history (`RecyclerView's` state etc.).

Thank you.

**Adapter for ViewPager:**

```
public class MainAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private Context mCtx;

public MainAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, int behavior, Context ctx) {
    super(fm, behavior);

    mCtx = ctx;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    return new NewsFragment();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 7;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    String tabTitle = "";

    if (mCtx != null) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                tabTitle = mCtx.getString(R.string.title_fragment_news);
                break;

            case 1:
                tabTitle = mCtx.getString(R.string.button_city_operation);
                break;

            case 2:
                // TODO
                tabTitle = "Tab 2";
                break;

            case 3:
                // TODO
                tabTitle = "Tab 3";
                break;

            case 4:
                tabTitle = mCtx.getString(R.string.title_fragment_information);
                break;

            case 5:
                tabTitle = mCtx.getString(R.string.title_fragment_announcement);
                break;

            case 6:
                // TODO
                tabTitle = "Tab7";
                break;
        }
    }

    return tabTitle;
}
}
```

**Init viewpager and tablayout**:

```
    MainAdapter mMainPagerAdapter = new MainAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT, getApplicationContext());
    ViewPager mViewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mMainPagerAdapter);
    // mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

    final TabLayout tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
```